# Make up down left right keys work in KornShell (ksh) Command line

Tags: shell, command-line, scripting, ksh, keymapping

Any update you can provide will be great.

When I put this in .profile:

```
set -o emacs 
alias __A=`echo "\020"`     # up arrow = ^p = back a command 
alias __B=`echo "\016"`     # down arrow = ^n = down a command 
alias __C=`echo "\006"`     # right arrow = ^f = forward a character 
alias __D=`echo "\002"`     # left arrow = ^b = back a character 
alias __H=`echo "\001"`     # home = ^a = start of line 
alias __Y=`echo "\005"`     # end = ^e = end of line
```

I can use the up/down keys for history.

But I want to edit from the command prompt using vi commands. I know `set -o vi` will do that, but then I lose the up/down key functionality provided by `set -o emacs`.

Bottom line is: I want to use the up/down/left/right arrow keys and I want to edit from the command prompt using vi commands. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [.vimrc dotfile](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#vimrc) to disable the bindings to special keys, then map each arrow motion from the [default vi keys](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html) to the cursor keys in normal mode using [angle bracket notation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#<>):

```
set cpo-=<
set exrc
set fileformats=unix,dos,mac
nmap k <Up>
nmap j <Down>
nmap h <Left>
nmap l <Right>
```

**References**

- [Vim Reference Manual: Key Mapping, 1.5: Mapping Special Keys](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/master/runtime/doc/map.txt#L451)
- [Vim Defaults](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/defaults.vim)
- [Setting Options: Appendix B - Learning the vi and Vim Editors, Seventh Edition - O'Reilly Media](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/linux/excerpts/9780596529833/setting-options.html)
- [`<CR>` not recognized as variable in VIM vimrc using PuTTY](https://superuser.com/questions/624732/cr-not-recognized-as-variable-in-vim-vimrc-using-putty)
- [How to escape angle brackets in mappings (the ones that appear in `<esc>` and `<cr>`)](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4610/how-to-escape-angle-brackets-in-mappings-the-ones-that-appear-in-esc-and-cr)
- [Basic Vim Tips](http://bencrowder.net/files/vim-fu/)